# Обновление привязки интерфейса

Tags: c#, wpf

В программе есть кнопка по нажатию которой пользователь может сбросить значения всех настроек к значению по умолчанию. Настройки хранятся в объекте `SettingsVM`.

Настроек достаточно много и чтобы не обнулять каждое свойство по отдельности я просто создаю новый объект.

```
public class MainVM : BaseVM
{
    public SearchVM SearchVM { get; set; }
    public static SettingsVM SettingsVM { get; set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        SearchVM = new SearchVM();
        SettingsVM = new SettingsVM();
        ResetSettingsCommand = new RelayCommand(ResetSettings);
    }

    public ICommand ResetSettingsCommand { get; }

    private void ResetSettings()
    {
        SettingsVM = new SettingsVM();
        OnPropertyChanged(String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что после отрабатывания метода `ResetSettings` интерфейс не меняется, а остается привязан к "старому" объекту.

Как исправить такое поведение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваше свойство `SettingsVM`, содержащее настройки, статическое. Для него интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` не работает. Сделайте свойство нестатическим.

Вам понадобится изменить и код привязки в XAML, для нестатических свойств он другой (проще).

Comment: Все VM наследуются от `BaseVM`, в котором реализован `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @maxwell: Изменил ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Без `static` работает.

Comment: @maxwell: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло.